# TagList vim plugin is not working

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I have issues in using `taglist`. For example if I `TlistOpen`, it shows an error `E117: Unknown function: taglist#Tlist_Window_Toggle`

I am using a Ubuntu18.04 , with vimrc looks like as follows;

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~/.vim/taglist/plugin$ cat ~/.vimrc
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/plugin/
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
" Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

Plugin 'taglist.vim'
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
set tags=/home/test/code/tags
```

I have my taglist cloned to `.vim/taglist/plugin`. My `Exuberant Ctags` is installed in `/usr/bin/ctags` and the path is available in `PATH`. I have installed the vim plugin manager `vundle`. I have my cscope and ctags set for the directory `code`. However when I `TlistOpen` in `vim`, it throws an error message `E117: Unknown function: taglist#Tlist_Window_Toggle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by removing all the comment noise from your `vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/plugin/
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
Plugin 'taglist.vim'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
set tags=/home/test/code/tags
```

as well as the examples that Vundle's `README.md` tells you to remove:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/plugin/
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'taglist.vim'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
set tags=/home/test/code/tags
```

and the irrelevant boilerplate:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/plugin/
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'taglist.vim'
call vundle#end()            " required
set tags=/home/test/code/tags
```

The first thing that catches the eye is that you are trying to manage that plugin both manually:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/plugin/
```

and with your plugin manager:

```
Plugin 'taglist.vim'
```

which doesn't make any sense.

The second thing that catches the eye is that you are adding `~/.vim/taglist/plugin/` to `:help 'runtimepath'` instead of `~/.vim/taglist/`, which prevents Vim from finding `~/.vim/taglist/autoload/` and thus from being able to call `taglist#Tlist_Window_Toggle()`.

Changing:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/plugin/
```

to:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/
```

should temporarily get you out of trouble but you will still be left with a mess.

I would suggest you abandon the manual method and let your plugin manager handle everything:

1. Delete `~/.vim/taglist/` from your machine.
2. Remove `set rtp+=~/.vim/taglist/` from your `vimrc`.
3. Replace `Plugin 'taglist.vim'` with `Plugin 'yegappan/taglist'` in your `vimrc`.
4. Read your plugin manager's documentation to get familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Could you let me know how to ```let your plugin manager handle everything```? What extra I shall do to make it handle by plugin manager?

Comment: @FrancM, see my edit. You have to *remove* the extra you added for no reason.